# How to Export correctly a standalone Game?

Tags: game-engine, export

I've finished the game I made and I wanted to export as runtime.

Firstly I installed the 2 necessary addons.

Then I read a couple of threads here and packed all into .blend and then made all external data relative. Afterwards I moved that .blend into a new empty folder and exported as runtime.

From the first look only the video-textures did not work but after I manually moved them to the folder where the executable is they were loading correctly (I guess making files relative had something to do with this working).

Now I moved the whole folder to a new pc( with the same OS-Windows10). I could not run it. So I downloaded blender and python there, in case the exported file is not like an executable(although it is .exe) but it still did not run.

Gave me a message like "contact the creator of this software".

So I think I messed up somewhere, and this brings me to my question. What are all the steps to export a BGE game so it can run to a new pc? And what are the requirements of the new pc to run it?

Edit: Tried running it, into a 3rd pc and it ran fine. This time the 3rd pc had OS-Windows 7(64bit). The 2nd pc that did not run it was 32bit and the pc it was created was 64bit. Anything I should know there?

Comment: If you exported it all into an exe it should be standalone and run on any computer by default, if it doesn't there must be something wrong. If I recall correctly you had sometimes to manually copy a bunch of DLL files from the Blender installation directory into your exe directory, though I haven't played with the game engine in ages.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one addon, is "required" that you have everything (textures, videos, others blends, sounds, etc.) in the same folder as your primary blend.

[image]

This highlighted files will be create when saving as runtime and they are required to be in the same folder of the .exe, if you are using only one blend and have already packed all external data you still require all that new files.

[image]

If you have this type of texture problem that I had while writing this answer:

[image]

**Notice the next block is not in the same order of the gif**

First i open the "blend file" and make paths relative and no change (but lol **i has editing the wrong file**...) so i pack all into blend and again no chage, then i almost realize and i set the textures names again then pack all and save the file and no change (lol). Finally i change de name of the file to load the want edit and the textures were there:

[image]

**Disclaimer**

I do not know if by repeatedly packing, make the blend file bigger.

**Notice** the file that i exported to run time is diferent from the one with the textures problem.
In the case of only one file after make the pack or repack, export it again to run time but this time dont need to check the copy of bundle and dlls.